# Does Toomey's amendment to the GOP Tax Bill only benefit Hillsdale College?

Tags: united-states, politics, law, taxes

Senate Minority Leader Chuck Schumer just said this on the Senate floor, regarding the Republican Tax Bill:

> One college, Hillsdale College, has been exempted from taxes on colleges with large endowments. It is supported by the DeVos family. This is a metaphor for how high the stench is rising in this chamber.

This is a reference to an amendment added by Republican Senator Pat Toomey, on page 295 of [this PDF](https://t.co/8ucaCpDXfI), which would exempt colleges which refuse federal funding from having to pay the Republican Tax Bill's endowment tax. My question is, is Chuck Schumer right that currently Toomey's amendment would only benefit Hillsdale College?

There are several colleges which refuse federal funding, but is Hillsdale College currently the only one that has a large enough endowment to be subject to the Republican Tax Bill's endowment tax?  If it helps, the endowment tax only applies to colleges with an endowment larger than $250,000 per full-time student.

Comment: Probably better on https://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since this question was posted, the amendment in question was voted down. However the question itself is still a valid one. https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/dec/02/us-tax-bill-democrats-attack-exemption-for-college-linked-to-betsy-devos

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the PDF linked doesn't match what the question says.  PDF may have changed.

Comment: @rjzii See: [Is “closer match to another SE” a reason to close an on-topic question as off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303203)